# What are these components used for in the Arduino Nano?

Tags: arduino, capacitor, resistors, schematics

What are the functions of the component(s) in the:

1. red
2. blue
3. green circle?

And what is a "+5V auto selector"?

[image: circuit of the arduino nano]

https://store.arduino.cc/products/arduino-nano

Answer (score 8):

Red and Green are bypass capacitors. The larger value capacitor is polarized and provides bulk capacitance. The 100nF caps are for high frequency bypassing and have low impedance at very high frequencies- typically they will be placed very close to the relevant pin that is drawing current.

Blue is one resistor out of a 4-resistor network 1K\$\Omega\$ with a number of resistors, and that particular portion is not used. The other three RP2A, RP2B, RP2D are used. Something like this (Yageo image from Mouser):

[image]

Four resistors with independent pins is a very common resistor array. Even if one, maybe two, resistors are unused it may be cheaper to use an array than individual resistors because there is less PCB area required and less mounting cost. Of course the resistors need to be the same value for standard networks (or you could combine, for example, two 1K in parallel to make 500 ohms in case one color of LED was particularly dim) and you'd get the equivalent of three discrete resistors of two values (2x 1K and 1x 500 ohms).

Answer (score 4):

1. Red components are for USB supply bypassing
2. Blue component is unused portion of a resistor network pack and has no function
3. Green components are for MCU supply bypassing

If you next ask what are bypass caps, they are basically filters to act as local energy storage so energy is quickly available if there is need to keep voltage stable, instead of having to suffer from voltage fluctuations while energy is delivered from a capacitor further away and connected with long wiring.

Answer (score 2):

Red is noise filtering and input power brown out protection. Typical decoupling capacitors. For the USB power input.

Green is the same, decoupling, physically and electrically close to the IC.

Quick changes in power draw from a load needs these little power banks to help prevent a low voltage due to the inductance of the trace that leads up to it. No change in power is instant even at the speed of light and these caps are used to solve that problem.

Blue is... weird. Looks like they tie an unused resistor from a resistor pack, to ground. This could be to prevent noise or interference from a floating pin from affecting the other pins in the resistor pack. Just good practice to not leave things floating. It does nothing else, electronically.